# Libre Calc> need to have notes within quotes within a formula not invalidate formula or calculation

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need a formula such as this one: =64*2+"testing"
to calculate to 128 not a #VALUE! error. I'm converting from Excel, and in Excel, it was necessary to turn on a switch for "transition evaluation." I can't find a way in Calc. I tried Tools - AutoCorrect - Options and deselecting replace double quotes. I don't want to have to go through and re-write hundreds of formulas in my existing spreadsheet.

Help?

Comment: What's the meaning of "testing" in that formula? Is is a reference / named range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to ignore the text and treat it as 0...
There is a setting:
Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula
In the **Detailed Calculation Settings** section, select "Custom"
Then click "Details..." button.
In the dropdown "Convert from text to number:", change to "Treat as Zero"
[image: Screen shot of Convert from text to number]

After you click through the OK, you may need to refresh the formula calculation by pressing: **Shift + Ctrl + F9**

Comment: H3coder, you are a GENIUS, much smarter than the AI's to which I asked the question!  And very helpful.  thank you so much for the answer, including the part about the recalculation, which I also needed.  I'm an excel pro, but a librecalc noob.     THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: I appreciate the remark, but per site policy, marking the solution as "Answer" would be enough and appreciated. Glad I could help. [See note about comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)